# why $env(LANG) throwing error even when env(LANG) exists in TCL?

Tags: environment-variables, tcl

Even when `env(LANG)` exists using `$env(LANG)` is throwing error saying `can't read "env(LANG)"`

its not just puts `$env(LANG)` even if I use it as

```
if ("" ne $env(LANG) ) {}
```

It still throws error.

Here is code:

```
if {[info exists env(LANG)]} { 

    puts "exists" 

} else {

    puts "not found" 

}

puts $env(LANG)
```

**output:**

```
exists 
ERROR: can't read "env(LANG)": no such variable
```

Can you please explain why such error may occur?

Comment: Add `parray env` and share the output.

Comment: Are you running this in tclsh or expect?

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess here... Do you call puts $env(LANG) from global or called scope?

This should work

```
puts $env(LANG)
```

This will not work

```
proc foo {} {
    puts $env(LANG)
}
foo
```

But this should work

```
proc foo {} {
    global env
    puts $env(LANG)
}
foo
```

Comment: Also `puts $::env(LANG)`

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD ONE TERMINAL MODE**

1.open the terminal

2.type tclsh

3.then use puts $env(LANG)

4.It will print en_US.UTF-8.

```
[ravi@cell041 ~]$ tclsh
% puts $env(LANG)
en_US.UTF-8
% puts $tcl_version
8.5
%
```

**METHOD 2 FROM A FILE**

1.create a file named as environment.tcl

2.Add the code into the file

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
 puts $env(LANG)
```

3.Run this file with tclsh environment.tcl and you may see the output at the terminal.

**METHOD 3**

1.create a file named as environment.tcl

2.Add the code into the file

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh


proc test {} {
   global env
   puts $env(LANG)
}

test
```

3.Run this file with tclsh environment.tcl and you may see the output at the terminal.

Please check whether tcl is installed properly in your system by typing.

```
 puts $tcl_version
```

If nothing is working check for parray env in terminal see whether that LANG key is present or not.

```
% parray env
env(LANG)= en_US.UTF-8
```